# Set Analysis - Current year and previous financial periods

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Trying to get the below code to run correctly, I want to get the `sum` of the field `movement` where the field `GlYear` is the same as what has been selected and the field `GlPeriod` is less than or equal to the period selected.

```
sum({$ <GlYear = {"{'1'} =$(=max(GlYear))"}, GlPeriod = {"{'1'} <=$(=max(GlPeriod))"}>}Movement)
```

I can't convert the two fields to dates as there are 16 financial periods within a year to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum({$ <GlYear = {"$(=max(GlYear))"}, GlPeriod = {"<=$(=max(GlPeriod))"}>}Movement)
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the {'1'}

My expression gives me this based on some quick test data

[image]

Tip it usually helps me figure out the set analysis by leaving the expression without a caption so that I can see the results of the $() expansion

Comment: That's perfect thanks, I'm still struggling with the basics of set analysis